# while loop inside for loop PHP

Tags: php

i'm trying to display a while loop depending on the parameters in my for loop.
for example, my for loop says to loop through 5 times, the data inside while loop should also be displayed 5 times. however, when i tested my code, the data inside while loop only displays once. i'm not sure if i did the iteration correctly. here is a snippet of my nested loop.

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

            echo "COUNT: ".$i."<br>";
            while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
                echo "INSIDE WHILE".$i."<br>";
                }

        }
```

so if my $count = 3, the output of this code is

```
0
INSIDE WHILE0
INSIDE WHILE0
INSIDE WHILE0
INSIDE WHILE0
INSIDE WHILE0
INSIDE WHILE0
INSIDE WHILE0

1

2
```

and what i want is for "INSIDE WHILE" to also be displayed between 1 and 2.

Comment: did you have the `mysqli_query()` code?

Comment: @RendiWahyudiMuliawan $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: Your `while` depends on the results of your query. If there are no more results to fetch, the while will not run again, regardless of how many times the `for` is run.

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM products";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: `while` loop is ended in the first iteration. as it fetch all records in a single-shot. that's why 1 and 2 are having blank

Comment: @IcedAnt i see. that's what i discovered also. are there any alternatives in which i can display the data inside my while loop while the my for loop is running?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Do you want to display the same data?

Comment: i tried doing this. $data[$i]=mysqli_fetch_array($res). still not working

Comment: @IcedAnt yep i want to display the same data inside the while loop.

Comment: Either run your query again (`$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);` after the `while` but still inside the `for`) or try @Jacobian 's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add [mysqli_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) after the while loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    echo "COUNT: ".$i."<br>";
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
        echo "INSIDE WHILE".$i."<br>";
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($res, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    echo "COUNT: ".$i."<br>";
    foreach ($data as $current_data){
          echo "INSIDE WHILE".$i."<br>";
          echo $current_data[name]; //name is the field name.
    }
}
```

You can move the fetch on top, so you don't have to reset the cursor of the fetch.